# How to map MySQL query result into an object based on distinct field results

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am working on an accounting application and am struggling to come up with a way to map query results to an object I can use on the front end. I have a MySQL query running through Node.js that is returning the following results:

```js
[
  RowDataPacket { ACCOUNT_TYPE: 'ASSET', TOTAL: 10000 },
  RowDataPacket { ACCOUNT_TYPE: 'LIABILITY', TOTAL: 250 },
  RowDataPacket { ACCOUNT_TYPE: 'EQUITY', TOTAL: 10000 },
  RowDataPacket { ACCOUNT_TYPE: 'REVENUE', TOTAL: 0 },
  RowDataPacket { ACCOUNT_TYPE: 'EXPENSE', TOTAL: 250 }
]
```

The query is such that the `ACCOUNT_TYPE` field will always have distinct results.

How can I convert this into an object like this?

```js
{ ASSET: 10000, LIABILITY: 250, EQUITY: 10000, REVENUE: 0, EXPENSE: 250 }
```

Comment: If all you want to do is turn your query results into the object format below, use 'reduce'.